# IIS 7 URL redirection using friendly URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a website running uder IIS 7,

```
https://example.com.xx/index.aspx
```

This application by design has very complex url which is not user friendly, I wanted to know is there any IIS 7 features which allows me to have a friendly URL which redirect the user to actual complex URL.

Friendly url could be,

```
https://example.com/company1
```

IIS needs to redirect the user to,

```
https://example.com.xx/XSDSDSNERERSRERERERERCSSSDMS<DSM<SMDS<DMSD<m
```

I need this,

- without changing my application
- without creating a website for redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this easily with the URL Rewrite extension (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). You can set up a single redirect as in your example by matching the URL exactly, or you can use wildcards or regular expression pattern matching.